# Why and When Cordova is better then React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to build an app using Cordova and I met a Web Developer he recomended using Native React saying these days React Native is the game winner over phone-gap...

So if you develop it in phone-gap, there is possibility that phone-gap get obsolete sooner. After doing some research about Native React and PhoneGap Cordova, they’re both awesome platform to build an app.

However, the app I’m trying to build should have a website too and With Cordova Wrapper you can build a hybrid application reusing the website codebase. You can have both web and mobile application from the same codebase. No matter how modern and cool the technology stack of the app is, users decide whether to use it or not based on 3 key points:

• The value the app brings to user’s life.

• The way it looks (design, animations and interactions).

• Performance (speed and consumed resources).

Anyone used both ?? What do you recommend ??

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that React Native renders a native UI, and Cordova renders a Web UI in a web container. So in Cordova, it's simply rendering a web page in a browser, with some hooks to communicate with native device features. A big advantage of this is that your Cordova will likely run 99% the same when deploying to the web, and you can use any web libraries and frameworks available to you.

In React Native, the UI elements map to the native UI frameworks for each platform, so it builds and renders a native UI based on the React DOM. It is fundamentally not the same UI code, whereas Cordova is (however all browsers don't render the same web code the same, but you get my point).

Cordova's not going anywhere for the time being, it's still a great set of tools. You can build hybrid apps with great performance, take a look at what the Ionic team are able to achieve:
https://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 
i choose cordova for simple SPA webapp with no features.
cordova is good to load local html contents.
cordova is good tocall api routes in ajax, in an SPA app.
Cordova is good to begin app developpement as rookie.

But if you need camera, geolocation, background service, etc... or some features using the hardware of the phone, i think cordova plugins and html5 API are not equal to react components or native component.

You can also take a look at flutter which is a good way to publish app on IOS and Android.